# Return changes from BLoC after changes in the Firestore

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, bloc

I'm doing some experiments with Flutter and met some problem. Basically, I'm using Flutter with BLoC pattern and Firestore as a remote store. I have something like this:

```
class HomeBloc extends Bloc<HomeEvent, HomeState> {

  ....

  @override
  Stream<HomeState> mapEventToState(HomeState state, HomeEvent event) async* {

   if(event is HomeEventStartTrackingWherlos) {
      Firestore.instance.collection('objects_collection')
      .snapshots()
      .listen((data) {
        var collection = List<MyObject>();
        data.documents.forEach((document) {
          MyObject mo = MyObject(document["name"], document["description"]);
          collection.add(mo);
        });

        // return HomeState.reloadedCollection(collection);
  });
}}
...
}
```

In line:

```
// return HomeState.reloadedCollection(collection);
```

I want to return new state with objects collection. If I simply *return* new state, then my *build* method in *StatefulWidget* isn't called. Do you have any suggestion how can I pass new state with collection after every change in the Firestore collection and based on that rebuild widget?